# how to send data from Kafka to Salesforce Streaming Api

Tags: streaming-api, kafka

i have done with the salesforce to Kafka already , i have some topics in KAFKA like Ptopic1 ,Ptopic2.

so the thing here is i want live data of some latitude and longitude that comes from MQTT. i am able to send it to the Kafka. why i chosen this because , even if my server down or something wrong, Kafka can hold my data and can be order, and later i can take back. i think my point is clear here.   one more thing here is i was able to directly connecting to MQtt on my Visual force page using some libraries and able to get data and able to plot this on my Visual force page.

Comment: As of now you cannot natively subscribe to the external bus.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal thanks for looking into , please check with my updates on the question and what i am trying to do.